# errors when trying to build boost filesystem in cygwin: error: expected unqualified-id before '&&' token

Tags: c++, boost

I have `cygwin 2.6` with `gcc 5.4` installed. I installed `boost.build` and it seems to be working. However when I try to build the filesystem module, it fails with the error:

```
work@PC /lib/boost_1_62_0/libs/filesystem/example/test
$ ./build.sh
Compiling example programs...
tut4.cpp:40:18: error: expected unqualified-id before '&&' token
tut4.cpp:40:18: error: expected ';' before '&&' token
tut4.cpp:40:23: error: expected ';' before ':' token
tut4.cpp:40:23: error: expected primary-expression before ':' token
tut4.cpp:40:23: error: expected ')' before ':' token
tut4.cpp:40:23: error: expected primary-expression before ':' token
tut4.cpp:45:18: error: expected unqualified-id before '&&' token
tut4.cpp:45:18: error: expected ';' before '&&' token
tut4.cpp:45:23: error: expected ';' before ':' token
tut4.cpp:45:23: error: expected primary-expression before ':' token
tut4.cpp:45:23: error: expected ')' before ':' token
tut4.cpp:45:23: error: expected primary-expression before ':' token
tut4.cpp:40:21: error: label 'x' used but not defined
../../../../boost/system/error_code.hpp: At global scope:
../../../../boost/system/error_code.hpp:221:36: warning: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not
 used [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  posix_category = generic_category();
../../../../boost/system/error_code.hpp:222:36: warning: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not use
d [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  errno_ecat     = generic_category();
../../../../boost/system/error_code.hpp:223:36: warning: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not us
ed [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  native_ecat    = system_category();
path_info.cpp:41:13: error: 'element' does not name a type
path_info.cpp:44:3: error: expected ';' before 'cout'
path_info.cpp:49:62: error: expected ')' before ';' token
../../../../boost/system/error_code.hpp: At global scope:
../../../../boost/system/error_code.hpp:221:36: warning: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not
 used [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  posix_category = generic_category();
../../../../boost/system/error_code.hpp:222:36: warning: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not use
d [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  errno_ecat     = generic_category();
../../../../boost/system/error_code.hpp:223:36: warning: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not us
ed [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  native_ecat    = system_category();
```

What should I do to fix this?

---

I install `b2` in `/usr/local/` and set `boost-build.jam` inside `/usr/local/share/boost-build` to have those value:

```
# Copyright 2001, 2002 Dave Abrahams
# Copyright 2002 Rene Rivera
# Copyright 2003 Vladimir Prus
# Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
# (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)


boost-build src/kernel ;
using gcc : 5.4 : g++-5.4 : <cxxflags>=c++11 ;  // Could it be that this settings is wrong or not applying during compilation?
```

---

I'm trying to follow instruction from [official boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html), which say I should go this way:

```
$ cd boost-root/libs/filesystem/example/test

$ ./setup.sh
Copying example programs...

$ ./build.sh
Compiling example programs...

$ ./tut1
Usage: tut1 path
```

Comment: Did you compile with C++11 turned on?

Comment: I update question with values of my `boost-build.jam` file

Comment: I hope that my changes inside `boost-build.jam` file make compiler work in c++11 mode, however I don't know how to chek that? Mybe they not affecting compilation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem caused by the fact, that you trying to build your code without `C++11` support, as was already mentioned in comments.

I'm not a `boost` expert, so actually couldn't say why settings from your `jam` file didn't apply and what is a correct order of resolving such settings in boost env, since I prefer write commands myself. However it will be really nice, if some one will be able to explain your mistake with `*.jam` files.

But for fixing your problem just use something like:

`b2 toolset=gcc cxxflags="-std=c++11" $* > build.log` instead of `./build.sh` and your project will compiled as expected.